# Silverlight datagrid header binding to constant

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, xaml

Say I have a bunch of local constants in my code behind that I want to use as headers, for example:

```
const string TYPE_HEADER = "Type";
const string LOCATION_ HEADER = "Location";
```

etc.

Is there any way I can bind the headers of my DataGridColumns to these like events are bound to local methods, for example:

```
<data:DataGridTextColumn Header="{Binding TYPE_HEADER}" />
```

Can this be done?  Perhaps by using some dynamic ResourceDictionary or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears this cannot be done without editing the control template for DataGridTextColumn as Header is not a FrameworkElement...

[Dynamically setting the Header text of a Silverlight DataGrid Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151682/dynamically-setting-the-header-text-of-a-silverlight-datagrid-column)

Comment: well can you do that and then try my solution?

Comment: I tried your solution, I got "System.Windows.Data.Binding" as my header using that approach.

Answer (score 1):

the TYPE_HEADER must be a string property (it can be backed by a const).  make a container:

```
public class MyStaticDataProvider
{
public string TYPE_HEADER { get { return "blkajsd"; } }
}
```

below the declaration of your usercontrol:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
<ResourceDictionary>
 <MyNamespace:MyStaticDataProvider x:Key="NameProvider" />
</ResourceDictionary>
</UserContro.Resources>
```

for your header:

```
Header="{Binding Path=TYPE_HEADER, Source={StaticResource NameProvider}, Mode=OneTime}"
```

it would be easier if silverlight supported x:Static, but it does not.  see [Silverlight 4 Equivalent to WPF "x:static"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3373926/silverlight-4-equivalent-to-wpf-xstatic)

Comment: I get "System.Windows.Data.Binding" as my header using this approach.